# PHP CLI don't call good php.ini

Tags: php, apache, openssl, command-line-interface

I try to install a project via composer on my ubuntu.
When I run `composer install` I have the error :

```
[RuntimeException]                                                 
You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https
```

My apache is installed under /etc/apache2 and php in /etc/php5
I have installed openssl and when I check install with phpinfo(), I see openssl is correctly enabled.

I know composer invoke php command line. 
So if I do this command :

```
php --ini
```

output

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

But there's no php.ini in /usr/local/lib

I don't know why php in command line take this configuration ?

thx

Comment: You should tell us how the php-cli binary materialized on your system. Did you try creating a ini in the local tree anyway?

Comment: php5-cli is installed (via apt-get) under /etc/php5/cli and have his own php.ini. Yes I tried to create ini no success

Answer (score 1):

I removed my php binary under /usr/local/bin and `php --ini` command now return php5 configuration :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
```